# convert this matrix equation into something numpy can understand

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I know how to solve basic linear matrix equations with numpy.

However, I have a matrix A and the equation A^2 + xA + yI = 0, where x and y are not vectors, but rather a scalar. I is the identity matrix, and 0 is the zero matrix of dimensions matching A.

This is a super easy on paper for small matrices (assuming of course that a solution exists), but I'm practicing for a coding interview and will be expected to solve problems like this with python. And maybe the matrix given will be quite large...

Here is a sample matrix A, which results in solutions x=-2, y=1:

```
np.array([[1,1,0],
          [0,1,0]
          [0,0,1]]
```

On paper, this is as easy as solving the system of linear equations x = -2 and x+y=-1. The issue I am facing is parsing the equation in its form above to one that is in the form of a system of equations (or alternatively a linear matrix equation of the form Ax = B).

Comment: `y` is also an unknown scalar?  So you are trying to find scalars `x` and `y` to satisfy the equation?

Comment: Yup! Will edit.

Comment: You say the problem is "super easy on paper for small matrices", but "small" must mean 2x2, because for larger matrices, in general, a solution will not exist.  You'll have more equations than unknowns.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser for some sparse matrices, it can work. There will be a repetition of equations, so the total number of unique equations will equal the total number of unknowns. The example I am going off of can be found here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/linear-algebra-foundations-6-the-nsupthsup-power-of-a-matrix/problem

Comment: Can you edit the question so we have all the relevant information here on stackoverflow?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I can, but I am looking for a general solution way to do this, not an answer to this specific problem. Give me one sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue I am facing is parsing the equation in its form above to one that is in the form of a system of equations (or alternatively a linear matrix equation of the form Ax = B

Say that *A* has *n* columns. For a square matrix *Q* with *n* columns, let *E(Q)* be the length-*n^2* vector formed by iterating over the entries of *Q* (say in row-major order).

Then solving for *x, y* in

*A^2 + xA + yI = 0*

is equivalent to solving for *z* in the system

*B z = -c*

where

- *z = [x, y]* is a length-2 column vector
- *B* is the *n^2 X 2* matrix whose columns are *E(A)* and *E(I)*
- *c* is *E(A^2)*

Comment: Ok, let me tr to work this out on my own and see how it goes. I'll accept your answer when I'm done :)

Comment: Ok so the dimensions of the set up Bz = -c are not compatible for matrix multiplication. B will be a 9x2 matrix multiplying a 1x2 vector. 

yet... when I do as you say and use linalg.lstsq(B, -c), I get the correct answer. Can you explain why?

Comment: @rocksNwaves Why incompatible? B is 9 X 2, but z - which is a column vector - is 2 X 1 (not as you wrote). So the product is 9 X 1, which is the dimension of c.